# hide ssrs textbox based on table data

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I can hide a table with no data by using this function in the **visibility expression** - =`Iif(CountRows() > 0, false, true)`

But I have a textbox used as a heading for the table. 
How do I hide the textbox if the table relating to it has no data?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=iif(countRows("DataSet2") > 0, false, true)
```

Where `DataSet2` is the name of your dataset.  This is because you are now informing the expression to Count the Rows in DataSet2.  As no rows exist, it is set to hidden.

*Further information...*

Is the heading for the table adjacent to the table?  Are you aware you can add rows above a table to provide extra heading information?

For example you can Right Click the Row Header, Select Insert Row -> Above and a new Row appears.  You can then merge the cells horizontally, and set a title for the table (for example)

Now when you set the table to be hidden, this header row is also hidden automatically.

[image]

I'm not sure this is applicable to your situation, but I thought it might be useful to add, to reduce the complexity of your report, if you were unaware of the possibility

Comment: Brill, please see the further information I added in case this is useful also

Comment: `=Not (countRows("DataSet2") > 0)` reduces the logic by one operation.